# How do dunder methods __getitem__ and __len__ provide iteration?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am reading about Python's dunder methods. One of the things I learned is that if a class provides an implementation for `__getitem__` and `__len__`, it can be used in a `for` loop.

Looking at the built-in classes like `list`, `tuple`, and `range` I noticed that all of them provide an implementation for `__iter__` which returns an iterator for a corresponding type. My understanding is that `for` loop uses this iterator to traverse the elements.

However, how does it work for a class which provides `__getitem__` and `__len__` but not an `__iter__`?

As an example, here's a `Range` class which mimics the in-built `range`:

```
class Range():
    def __init__(self, start, stop=None, step=1):
        if step == 0:
            raise ValueError('step cannot be 0')

        if stop is None:
            start, stop = 0, start

        self._length = max(0, (stop - start + step - 1) // step)

        self._start = start
        self._step = step

    def __len__(self):
        return self._length

    def __getitem__(self, k):
        if k < 0:
            k = len(self) + k

        if not 0 <= k < self._length:
            raise IndexError('Index out of range')

        return self._start + (k * self._step)
```

Iterating over it with a `for` loop:

```
In [21]: for elem in Range(5):
    ...:     print(elem)
    ...: 
0
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A iterable is a class which defines either `__iter__` or `__getitem__`, no need for `__len__`.

The difference between the `__iter__` implementation and the `__getitem__` implementation is:
`__iter__` calls `__next__` on the object that returned from `__iter__` (aka iterator), until it reaches `StopIteration` and that's where the for loop stops.
However `__getitem__`, starts from zero (always), and each iteration it increments by one, until it reaches `IndexError`, and it does that by `obj[idx]`.

For instance:

```py
class GetItem:
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if idx == 10:
            raise IndexError
        return idx
        
for i in GetItem():
    print(i)
```

The result will be

```
0
1
2
...
9
```

because as soon as the index gets to 10, it raises `IndexError` and the loop stops.

`__iter__` on the other hand,

```py
class Iter:
    def __iter__(self):
        self.n = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.n += 1
        if self.n == 10:
            raise StopIteration
        return self.n
        
for i in Iter():
    print(i)
```

Here, you need to keep track of the state by yourself, whereas in `__getitem__` it does it by itself, it's better for counting/indexing and such.

Comment: "However __getitem__, starts from zero (always)"

Is that really the case? In dictionaries, doesn't `__getitem__` take the dictionary's keys?

Comment: @krm There is a precedence for `__iter__` over `__getitem__` (the `__getitem__` will take the control over the iteration just if there is no `__iter__` defined). In dictionaries, there is `__iter__` defined which returns an iterator over the keys of the dict, and the `__getitem__` returns the value for a particular key, as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement `for x in y: ...` in two ways.

1. Rewrite as an infinite `while` loop that calls `next` explicitly.

   ```
   itr = iter(y)  # Using __iter__
   while True:
       try:
           x = next(itr)
       except StopIteration:
           break
       ...
   ```
2. Rewrite as an iteration over `range(len(y))`:

   ```
   for i in range(len(y)):  # Using __len__
       x = y[i]  # Using __getitem__
       ...
   ```

   This relies on `__getitem__` being defined for indices 0 through `len(y) - 1`.

---

Update: as @Jonathon1609 reminds me, `__len__` is not used. Instead, the `for` loop requires `__getitem__` to raise an `IndexError` to terminate iteration.

```
i = 0
while True:
    try:
        x = y[i]  # Uses __getitem__
    except IndexError:
        break
    ...
    i += 1
```

`reversed` is the function that can use `__len__` and `__getitem__` together if `__reversed__` is not defined.

Comment: this is helpful. Is this how `for` loop works internally, too? What's going on under the hood with the custom `Range` class?

Comment: No, an iterator with `__getitem__` isn't done as you said.

Comment: @AnSOUser Under the hood, a `for` loop is (mostly) equivalent to the `while` loop, though with some modifications to handle the `else` clause (and it doesn't create a visible variable `itr` in the current scope).